# Flutter - Trying to Use Tensorflowlite - FloatEfficientNet

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel, flutter-android

I am attempting to use a model that is successfully inferencing in both native swift and android/java to do the same in flutter, specifically the android side of it.

In this case the values I am receiving are way off.

What I have done so far:

1. I took the tensorflowlite android example github repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android, and found that the FloatEfficientNet option was accurately giving values for my model.
2. I took the flutter_tflite library, and I modified it so that the inferencing section of the android code matched that tensorflow example above:
   https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite
3. I used this tutorial and included repo which uses the above library to inference tensorflow via the platform channel:
   https://github.com/flutter-devs/tensorflow_lite_flutter

Via the flutter tutorial, I use the camera plugin, which can stream CameraImage objects from the camera's live feed. I pass that into the modified flutter tensorflow library which uses the platform channel to pass the image into the android layer. It does so as a list of arrays of bytes. (3 planes, YuvImage). The tensorflow android example(1) with the working floatefficientnet code, examples a Bitmap. So I am using this method to convert:

```
    public Bitmap imageToBitmap(List<byte[]> planes, float rotationDegrees, int width, int height) {

        // NV21 is a plane of 8 bit Y values followed by interleaved  Cb Cr
        ByteBuffer ib = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 2);

        ByteBuffer y = ByteBuffer.wrap(planes.get(0));
        ByteBuffer cr = ByteBuffer.wrap(planes.get(1));
        ByteBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.wrap(planes.get(2));
        ib.put(y);
        ib.put(cb);
        ib.put(cr);

        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(ib.array(),
                ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);
        byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        Bitmap bitmap = bm;

        // On android the camera rotation and the screen rotation
        // are off by 90 degrees, so if you are capturing an image
        // in "portrait" orientation, you'll need to rotate the image.
        if (rotationDegrees != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotationDegrees);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
                    bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

The inference is successful, I am able to return the values back to flutter and display the results, but they are way off. Using the same android phone, the results are completely different and way off.

I suspect the flaw is related to the conversion of the CameraImage data format into the Bitmap, since it's the only piece of the whole chain that I am not able to independently test. If anyone who has faced a similar issue could assist I am rather puzzled.

Comment: are you sure that the reason does not come from your float rotationDegree? Have you tried with an integer? Because rotationdegrees impact your matrix which itself impact your bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because `matrix.postRotate()` method expect an integer but you give it a float, so you have an implicit conversion from float to integer which messes it up.